# How to start a linux shell as from /etc/inittab

Tags: bash, interactive, init, job-control

We used to have two entries in our /etc/inittab:

```
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS
ttyS0::respawn:-/bin/sh
```

rcS is a shell script which normally starts our application, but in a special case we called "return" to terminate it which apparently lets the /bin/sh take over the tty as we got a shell prompt where we could do some maintenance.

Now the inittab looks like this:

```
::once:/etc/init.d/rcS
```

We now start the shell by executing "/bin/bash -i" in the rcS script, as we don't want to always run a second shell (due to memory constraints) which is normally never used.

But the created bash doesn't feature job control, which is very limiting.

So my question is, can I create a shell (and maybe terminate the rcS script) the same way the init processed did in our previous solution so that I get again a shell with job control?

Comment: You'd probably get a better answer on superuser.com, but I would try `exec login -f root` where you currently have the `/bin/bash -i`.  I *think* that sets up the terminal correctly.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on exactly what OS you are running.  Here is an example which works on RHEL/CentOS.

```
6:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty --autologin root tty6
```

Here is what someone else did for a similar trick.

```
openvt -f -c 12 -w -- sh -c "unicode_start; echo -e '$NORPT'; exec $LOGINSH" >/dev/tty1
```